# Is the MCP language really np hard?

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs

I have a graph $G=\left(V , E\right)$ and source $s$ and target $t$.

I also have a weight function $w: V\rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}^k$, meaning a vertex given $k$ non negative weights.

There is an upper bound vector $C \in \mathbb{R^+}^k$.

The problem definition is to find a path from $s$ to $t$ such that it is not too heavy.

What too heavy means? For each $1<i<k$ the coordinate $i$ for the weight of a path (sum of edges...) must be smaller than $C_i$.

I read somewhere that this problem is np hard, but I don't think it is. I think its solvable by running many iterations that any shortest (by $w_i$) weight path. And then iterating over again.

I want to ask if my approach is correct or if its not and its really np hard, how you show it?

Comment: In order to check whether the algorithm is correct we will need a way more detailed explanation of the algorithm that you have in mind than the one you gave in your answer. Also, have you tried coming up with a formal proof?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is NP-hard even for $k=2$, as it can be seen by a reduction from the partition problem.

The reduction is as follows:
Let $S = \{s_1, \dots, s_n\}$ be a set of $n$ positive integers.
Let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2n}$.

Create a graph that has $n+1$ vertices numbered from $1$ to $n+1$ and $2n$ edges. Specifically, for each $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ add two parallel edges* $e_i$ and $f_i$ between $s_i$ and $s_{i+1}$. Pick $w(e_i) = (s_i,\varepsilon)$ and $w(f_i) = (\varepsilon, s_i)$. Pick $C = (T, T)$, where $T =\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n s_i$.

There is a path from vertex $1$ to vertex $n+1$ of total weight at most $C$ if and only if there is a subset $S'$  of $S$ such that $\sum_{s \in S'} s = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n s_i$.

If you multiply all involved weights by $2n$, you can show that the problem remains hard even when all numbers involved are positive integers. Moreover, a similar reduction from the 3-partition problem shows that this special case is strongly NP-Hard.

* Here I'm using parallel edges for simplicity but the graph can be made simple by splitting the edges with an intermediate vertex and tweaking the edge weights.

The following graph with $C=(50,50)$ is a counterexample to your algorithm. All unlabelled edges have weights $1,1$.

[image: coutnerexample]

Comment: Because you required weights to be positive, so I can't use $0$ and must use a small value $\varepsilon$ instead. The contribution of all $\varepsilon$s to each entry of the weight will be at most $\frac{1}{2}$. The reduction doesn't work if $k=1$. I'm not sure how you are thinking of redefining the edge weights but you can try proving the correctness of the reduction formally to see where it breaks down. Regarding your algorithm: I would provide a counterexample but its description is still too vague for me. You could formalize it using pseudocode.

Comment: I added a counterexample to my answer. Can you add a description of the algorithm to your question, so it is clear for everybody (without digging thought the comments?)